# AJAX Post - Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Well, first of all hello to all ;) And thanks in advance!

Well, my problem is the following. I'm making a web with codeigniter, bootstrap and jquery and i have problems when loading a new view.

When I want to load a new view after a post i'm not able to do it. If i do not make post all goes well and the `$this->load->view('template', $data);` opens the next page correctly.

The thing is that if i make an AJAX post from the view, let's say that i want to go to a previous page with a button. So i make

```
$('#backlink').click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: url + "select_campus_controller/index",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        });
```

This will have to open the new view with the controller method index which calls the new view

```
public function index() {
    $data = array();
    $data['content'] = "v_select_campus";
    $data['title'] = "Select faculty";
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

The thing is that instead of opening the new view I only get all the html code in data and i cannot open the page. Should it open it directly or do i have to do something?

**Edition:**

The thing is that i don't want to put specific section of the web. When i call

```
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

I'm calling template.php which makes a whole new page:

```
<?php

 $this->load->view('includes/header');

 $this->load->view($content);

 $this->load->view('includes/footer');

?>
```

and with `$data['content'] = "v_select_campus";` i select the section that i want to load in the middle of the page. But instead of getting the page i get all the page as a string in the success of the post.

I'm not sure if i'm understanding it right all the view thing...

Comment: write the data from ajax success response to an element

Comment: And if i'm loading the whole page with $this->load->view('template', $data); what do i do?

Comment: if you want to open a new page just use window.open in ajax success

Comment: Ok. I will try it. But this will open it in a new page? I want to put all the new view (which is the whole page) in the same page not in a new one

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#backlink').click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: url + "select_campus_controller/index",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('$div1').html(unescape(data));

                }
            });

        });


<div id="div1"></div>
```

then the view 'template' will be diaplayed on the div with id **div1**.

Comment: I guess that is for updating an especific div but i want to load a whole new page which i get as string in success data...

Answer (score 0):

You can directly redirect page on Button Click, By using AJAX request you can update the contents of element, Loading views is done on Server side by Code Ingiter

Comment: Any guess of how can i load views when i make a post? Or is it impossible?

Comment: In Base page from where you are sending ajax Request, create div as place holder for HTML output your getting from url + "select_campus_controller/index" i.e. ajax response and load that output in placeholder using following:
    $('#div_id').html(data);

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this :

```
$('#backlink').click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: url + "select_campus_controller/index",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('html').html(data);
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, in code igniter load view you can pass third parameter.

```
public function index() {
    $data = array();
    $data['content'] = "v_select_campus";
    $data['title'] = "Select faculty";
    $d = $this->load->view('template', $data,TRUE);
   echo $d
}
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.